# Trying to fetch product featured image from WP API Json data using javascript

Tags: json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

please am new to APIs, how can I go about fetching product featured images into my custom HTML page from WP API Json data using javascript? below is what I've done but the featured image refused to show up, and if there's any better way of doing this I'll like to know.

````
const url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/product?filter[categories]=dishes&media';
    
    const postsContainer = document.querySelector('.product_title');

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => 
        {
            data.map( product => {
                const innerContent = 
                `
                 <div class="ltabs-item product-layout">
                                            <div class="product-item-container">
                                                <div class="left-block">
                                                    <div class="product-image-container second_img ">
                                                        <img src="product._link.wp:featuredmedia.0.href.source_url"  alt="featured image 30" class="img-responsive" />
                                                        <img src="image/demo/shop/resize/J5-270x270.jpg"  alt="Apple Cinema 30&quot;" class="img_0 img-responsive" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--Sale Label-->
                                                    <span class="label label-sale   ">-15%</span>
                                                    <!--full quick view block-->
                                                    <a class="quickview iframe-link visible-lg" data-fancybox-type="iframe"  href="quickview .html">  Quickview</a>
                                                    <!--end full quick view block-->
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="right-block">
                                                    <div class="caption">
                                                        <h4>${product.title.rendered}</h4>      
                                                        <div class="ratings">
                                                            <div class="rating-box">
                                                                <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                                                                <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                                                                <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                                                                <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                                                                <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                            
                                                        <div class="price">
                                                            <span class="price-new">$50.00</span> 
                                                            <span class="price-old">$62.00</span>        
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                      <div class="button-group">
                                                        <button class="addToCart" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Cart" onclick="cart.add('42', '1');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="">Add to Cart</span></button>
                                                        <button class="wishlist" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Wish List" onclick="wishlist.add('42');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
                                                        <button class="compare" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Compare this Product" onclick="compare.add('42');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
                                                      </div>
                                                </div><!-- right block -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                `
                postsContainer.innerHTML += innerContent;
            })
        }
    );```
````

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

You've set your postsContainer variable as a constant, which should resist being changed further on. This could be your problem. Try setting this with let or var.

```
let postsContainer = document.querySelector('.product_title');
```

Work through the script more gradually by testing the code so you can see where the failure is.

1. console.log() the data response to ensure you are connecting to the API and getting a response that contains the product objects.

```
console.log('data: ', data);
```

2. console.log() the returned data progressively within the loop until you are certain you have the URLs.

```
console.log('product: ', product);
console.log('product: ', product._link);
etc
```